# Making sure nobody can view the file directory on my machine

Tags: security, http

How can I prevent external users from somehow getting a list of files that are on my machine?

For instance, My website is in folder /htdocs/ and I have some other random documents in there too.

How do I make sure that the user can only see the site and can never get an overview of what files I have on that harddrive?

Comment: Seems like a ServerFault question to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Apache, you can create a `.htaccess` file like this:

```
 Options -Indexes
```

For more details, check out How to Prevent a Directory Listing of Your Website with .htaccess

Answer (score 4):

assuming apache look at this page for some good security tips

in specific add to httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
 </Directory>

<Directory /htdocs>
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Comment: Directory entries very much like these are default, but it's a good idea to check to make sure. +1

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could restrict the apache user via SELinux policy. If you are on a system with SELinux that is...

Look at his article on [secure containers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lxc-security/index.html) (lightweight virtual machines). Perhaps for the more paranoid or those who have problems of scale.